# add audio to ffmpeg video stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, stream

I have a ffmpeg command that takes a stream of frames and pipes out a ogg video. How can I add audio to this from another file?

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s WIDTHxHEIGHT -r 30 -i - -f ogg -an -qscale:v 10 pipe:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another -i parameter to add another input source.

However, your -an parameter disables audio entirely, so you'll need to remove that.

This worked for me when I tested it:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s WIDTHxHEIGHT -r 30 -i - -i audio.mp3 -f ogg -qscale:v 10 pipe:1
```

Comment: This shouldn't work. You have retained `-an` from the OP's command thus disabling audio.